# how to convert a string that i got from the text() widget into a list of int Data type?

Tags: python, tkinter, logic

so I'm trying to create a small GUI application that can take data from the user from the text() widget example:112,21,33,49,5 or 12 21 33 49 5 and sort or searches the list according to the Users choice. But I'm now stuck at this problem.

the problem is my logic is working for single-valued data like 9,8,3,5,2,6 but it is totally rubbish when I give data such as 99,22,44,11. It counts each individual item and then performs the rest of the operation. Help me with the logic, please.

## This is the code to take data from the widget and convert into int and append the int data into another blank list b[].

```
 b = []
    a12 = entry_01.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    for k in a12:
        if k != ",":
            c = int(k)
            b.append(c)
```

After the list b[] is ready after appending all data I then apply the searching or sorting algorithms. S I only need help with this portion of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
a12 = entry_01.get()
a13 = a12.split(",")
b = []
for k in a13:
    b.append(int(k))
```

Answer (score 2):

If they will always be split by commas, something as simple as this will work:

```py
b = list(map(int, a12.split(",")))
```

If they can be either spaces or commas, using a simple regex string would suffice:

```py
b = list(map(int, re.split("[\s,]+", a12.strip()))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, your answer is on SPOT.